# Jquery how to set panel height dynamically based on its children height

Tags: jquery

How to set bootstrap panel height dynamically based on its children height.

I have the below code

```
<div class='panel panel-default col-sm-12 col-md-6 panel-container' id='1_panel'>
    <p>
        <input type="text">
    </p>
</div>
```

Here if I type something in the input field, based on its width and height, the style attribute should be added automatically in the panel div and change its value whenever the input width and height changes.

It should be like the below one.

```
<div class='panel panel-default col-sm-12 col-md-6 panel-container' id='1_panel' style="width:100px; height: 200px">
```

How to achieve this even if I have style attribute in the panel div initially or not.

Comment: type display type as flex for div , style="display:flex"

Comment: Hi Rana, Many thanks for your quick reply. I tried it but it's not showing width and height in the style attribute when seeing in the developer tools on the screen. I need the same in input tag also. Means initially there won't be style attribute in the input and panel tag. But, we type something in the input field, both panel and input filed should have the style attribute and change values dynamically. Is it possible?